# Change dynamically FontAwesomeIconView

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to change dinamically a `FontAwesomeIconView`
[image]

The controller has defined with:

```
@FXML
private FontAwesomeIconView star;

public void initializeNow() {
    try {
          if(!client.getUser().getFavoriteList().contains(client.getAuction(auction.getId()))) { //Se l'asta non e' tra le preferite
            star = new FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.STAR_ALT);

        }
        else {
            star = new FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.STAR);
        }
...}
```

I check if an user has the selected auction in his favourite list and if is true i change the icon (`ANCHOR`) but it doesn't change. Why?

Comment: Changing a field’s value does not change which nodes have been added to your Scene.  Instead of creating a new FontAwesomeIconView, call `setIcon` on the existing one.  (Side note: A lot of FontAwesome glyphs can be achieved without FontAwesome, using Labels or Text nodes containing Unicode codepoints.  For instance, star and star-alt can be simply `label.setText("\u2605")` and `label.setText("\u2606")`, respectively.  An anchor is `label.setText("\u2693")`.)

Comment: @VGR thanks, i had forgotten it, I upvote your comment because is so useful!
Thank you!